# Why did Yonah run away?

Tags: theology, navi-prophets, yonah-jonah-book-of

If Yonah understood that he was being commanded by God, then how could he have possibly thought that he could run away?  Did he believe that God was tied to a particular land, the way pagan gods were thought to be tied to theirs, and that if he just got out of Israel he would be ok?  But Nineveh is not in Israel either.  At the time he ran, did Yonah perhaps not yet understand Who was commanding him?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yonah was a navi who was living in the kingdom of Israel before its exile by Sancheriv. God told him to go to Ninveh, which was in Ashur.

In general, God is not concerned enough with the affairs of non jewish nations to send them messages through a navi to repent, which is why they don't have their own prophets to begin with. Yonah concluded that their repentance must be relevant to Israel in some way, particularly to exile them from their land. (Yonah knew that the Jews weren't on the highest spiritual level at that point.)

Therefore, Yonah refused to go, not wanting to play any part in Israel's destruction. He hoped that God would choose another navi in his place, as clearly, if God wanted this done, it must be necessary. But not him. To try and ensure this, Yonah tried to flee to outside of Eretz Yisrael, as he believed that nevua does not exist outside of the land (which is true, with few exceptions). Thus, he thought, God would be forced to send someone else.

See Abarbanel (Yonah 1).

Comment: Yonah figured that if the people of Ninveh would listen to G-d's word and repent, it would make the Jewish people look that much worse for not repenting. He therefore tried to get out of delivering the message to them. (I don't know if it is the Abarbanel who makes this point).

Comment: @Menachem [Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=181)

Comment: Didn't non-Jews also have Bilam for a navi?  And who's to say there aren't others among the non-Jews?

Comment: why God isn't concerned with fate of non jewish people considering that many jews would live among them for quite a while.

Answer (score 6):

I heard an innovative explanation from Rav Meir Spiegelman.  Yonah doesn't run away to get to a different place; Yonah sets sail in order to be at sea, and there is no prophecy at sea.

This is related to the idea that the sea is too different from the earth to be involved in earth-based things (e.g. fish are created from the water, but animals from the earth; fish were not punished during the flood; fish are never brought as sacrifices).

Specifically regarding Yonah, this issue is explained by [the Malbim](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%92):

> לכן עלה אל האניה, שחשב שבעת יהיה באניה לא תחול עליו רוח ה', אם מפני שיורדי הים דעתם בלתי מתישבת מצער הים עד בואם ליבשה כמ"ש חז"ל, אם מפני שאז לא יתבודד באשר היו על האניה עובדי אלילים שכ"ז תעכב בל תשרה השכינה עליו.‏

(Therefore he went to the ship, since he thought that when he would be in the ship the Divine Presence would not rest on him, either because those who set sail have unfocused thoughts from the difficulty of the sea until they come to dry land, as our sages have said, or because then he could not be alone, as there were idol worshipers on the ship; that all this would prevent the Divine presence from resting on him.)

Comment: Interesting!  I had not previously heard that there is no prophecy at sea.  There are still miracles at sea (Noach, Sea of Reeds, and of course Yonah's fish), but not direct divine command?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, note that Noach is spoken to only before the flood starts, and after it all dries out--there is no Divine communication in the ark, even when it's at rest, until the earth is dry. At the Red Sea, the people are on dry land the whole time.

Comment: no prophecy at sea? Ra'asa shifcha al hayam ma sh'lora'asah yechezkel ben buzi

Comment: @PM, the Jews were on dry land the whole time!

Answer (score 4):

The answer that [Menachem gave](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18902/603) is brought up by Rashi on the pasuk. The question still remains, what did he thought he would achieve by running away? This reminds me of the situation in which Moshe Rabenu told Hashem, Shemot 32:32, that if you don't pardon Am Yisrael "omit me" from your book. Out of love to Am Yisrael he didn't want to be part of the punishment. Same here: Yonah, out of love to Am Yisrael, doesn't want to be part of disgracing Am Yisrael, so he uses his Bechira chofshit (free will?) and prefers to die and not be part of the plot.

Answer (score 3):

The Shechinah doesn't rest outside of Israel, so Yonah hoped to not get nevuah ([Rashi and Radak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=181)).

Comment: _Moderation Notation: This answer was penned to a different version of this question and moved hither._

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the Abarbanel [brought by @jake](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11512/603), [Rashi says](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=181) that Yonah figured that if the people of Ninveh would listen to G-d's word and repent, it would make the Jewish people look that much worse for not repenting. He therefore tried to get out of delivering the message to them.

Answer (score 2):

[R. Saadia Gaon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon) explains (Emunot V’Deiot 3:5) that Yonah had fulfilled his mission:

> If, furthermore, one were to ask, “But how was it that Jonah was chosen to carry out a mission from which he ran away, when it would seem that the All-Wise would not choose anyone who would disobey him?” I would answer that I have gone over the story of Jonah repeatedly and yet have not found a single verse that would state explicitly that he did not fulfill his first mission. And although I have not found a definite indication that he carried it out either, yet I feel constrained to believe that he did, in the same manner in which all the prophets did. Another reason is that the All-Wise would not choose anyone to execute an errand of His who would not carry it out. Besides, I find Scripture saying constantly: *And the Lord spoke unto Moses, saying: Speak unto the children of Israel* (Lev. 23:1, 2). Yet it is only in a few instances that the comment was made that the command was carried out, as it is done [in the statement]: *And Moses spoke so unto the children of Israel* (Exod. 6:9).
>
> What Jonah fled from was  only the possibility of his being sent on a mission a second time. For it seemed to him that his first mission constituted a warning, but that the second was an act of intimidation and a threat. He was, therefore, afraid that, after his having threatened them with some punishment or other, those to whom he would be sent would repent so that the threat would not be carried out and it would be said that it was due to his having lied. Hence he departed from the land which the Creator had appointed to be the seat of prophecy.
>
> All this is explicitly stated at the end of Jonah’s remark: *I pray Thee, O Lord was not this my saying, when I was yet in mine own country? Therefore I fled beforehand into Tarshish* (Jonah 4:2). No sin attached to him, therefore, since his Lord had not told him: “I am going to send thee a second time.” That was merely a thought that had arisen in his mind, and he rejected what might perhaps come or not come to pass. Thereupon God made him return by compulsion to the country that had been singled out for prophecy, and brought him to the point of prophesying, and sent him forth on his mission and thus executed [the plan conceived by] His wisdom.
>
> (Rosenblatt translation p. 153-154)

Answer (score 1):

This question was posed to [Radbaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) (Shu"t 2:842).

He essentially has three suggestions.

1) It was not considered withholding his prophecy (which is punishable by death) because he hadn't yet received the prophecy. He had only been told by God to go to Nineveh, and he felt that it would be better to passively violate that command in order for the Jews not to look bad that they don't repent while non-Jews do.

2) This was Yonah's first time prophesying, and because of the Jewish honor that was at stake it was too difficult for him to follow God's command. Had he told God his objections (as Moshe did) he would not have been punished. Instead he fled, thinking that outside of Israel it is impossible to receive prophecy. His mistake was that this is only true of the beginning of prophecy. Once a prophet has already prophesied in Israel he can continue receiving prophecy outside of Israel, as we see by Yechezkel.

3) Yonah planned on eventually fulfilling his mission; he was merely stalling in the hope that his mission would become irrelevant.

> שאלת ממני ידיד נפשי על מה סמך יונה בן אמיתי לברוח ולא רצה ללכת בשליחות
>   השי"ת וכבש נבואתו הא קי"ל נביא שכבש נבואתו חייב מיתה     תשובה את זו
>   לא שמעתי כיוצא בה שמעתי ששאלו לפני הרשב"א ז"ל על עדו הנביא שעבר על
>   דבריו שהחזירו הזקן ואכל ושתה עמו ונענש ואכלו ארי והשיב ז"ל כי זה הזקן
>   היה בתחלה נביא אמת ולבסוף נעשה נביא שקר ועדו הנביא היה מסתפק בנבואתו
>   שמא דוקא בביאה ראשונה אמרו לו שלא יאכל ולא ישתה אבל בביאה שנייה מותר
>   ולפיכך האמין לדברי הזקן שחשב שנתנבא באמת לפי שהיה מוחזק בו שהוא נביא
>   ונענש לפי שלא היה מותר לאכול שם עד שיגידו לו בעצמו בנבואה שהוא מותר
>   והביא ראיה מיונה בן אמיתי שאמרו לו ונינוה נהפכת והוא חשב לרעה ולא היה
>   כן אלא שנהפכה מרעה לטובה כדאיתא בפרק הנחנקין זה תורף דבריו ז"ל ובנ"ד
>   ליכא לתרוצי הכי שהרי לא היה לו במה לתלות ולדעת מי שמפרש דלא נאמרה לו
>   הנבואה אלא לבסוף כי בתחלה לא נאמר לו אלא שילך אל נינוה ומה שכתב וקרא
>   עליה כי עלתה רעתם לפני הוא מה שאמר לו לבסוף וקרא עליה את הקריאה אשר
>   אני דובר אליך יש לתרץ דאין כאן כובש נבואה דאכתי לא נאמרה לו הנבואה ואי
>   משום דעבר על מה שאמר לו הקב"ה קום לך אל נינוה דאיפשר דסמך לו לעבור בשב
>   ואל תעשה משום תקנתן של ישראל שלא יהיה עליהם תרעומת שהעכו"ם שבים בתשובה
>   וישראל אין שומעין אל דברי הנביאים יום השכם ושלוח אבל יש להקשות שאם לא
>   נאמרה לו הנבואה מנא ידע שהם רשעים ושהקב"ה מצוה שיקרא עליהם שעלתה רעתם
>   לפניו עד שהוכרח לברוח לחוצה לארץ כדי שלא תחול עליו הנבואה אבל הנכון
>   שנאמר לו הנבואה בתחלה כפי מה שנראה מפשט הכתוב ומדברי רז"ל ובעיקר השאלה
>   יש לומר דבין למ"ד שלא נתנבא אלא על נינוה בין למ"ד שנבואה אחרת היתה לו
>   דכתיב בספר מלכים הוא השיב את גבול ישראל מלבוא חמת עד ים הערבה כדבר ה'
>   אלהי ישראל אשר דבר ביד עבדו יונה בן אמיתי הנביא אשר מגת החפר לדעת כולם
>   זאת היתה הנבואה הראשונה ומה שכתוב ויהי דבר ה' אל יונה בן אמיתי שנית הא
>   אמרו שנית ולא שלישית והקשו ולא והא כתיב אשר דבר ביד עבדו יונה בן אמיתי
>   וגומר ותירצו על עסקי נינוה לא דבר עמו אלא פעם שנית ולא שלישית משמע דעל
>   עסק אחר דבר עמו שלישית מכל מקום זאת היתה ראשונה לשליחותו בנבואה והיה
>   קשה עליו מפני כבודן של ישראל וכן אמרו בהדיא רבותינו ז"ל יונה תבע כבוד
>   הבן ולא תבע כבוד האב וכיון שכן היה מסרב בשליחות ולא קבלו עליו כמאמר
>   אדון הנביאים שלח נא ביד תשלח ואם היה אומר לפניו אני יודע שהעכו"ם נוחים
>   לשוב בתשובה ויש בזה קלקול גדול לישראל ומשום הכי תשלח ביד נביא אחר לא
>   היה נענש אלא העונש היה מפני שברח וטעה בחושבו שלא תחול עליו הנבואה
>   בחוצה לארץ וליתא דלא אמרינן הכי אלא בתחלת הנבואה אינה שורה בחוצה לארץ
>   אבל אם קבל כבר הנבואה בארץ ישראל איפשר שתחול עליו גם בחוצה לארץ
>   ויחזקאל הנביא יוכיח ושב בתשובה שלימה והתפלל ממעי הדגה ונענה     כללא
>   דמלתא מסרב בשליחות היה מפני כבודן של ישראל ולא היה כובש נבואתו ולא
>   עובר על דברי עצמו ואע"פי שהיה יודע שיענש בשביל כך אמר מוטב שיענש הוא
>   ולא יפול מכבודן של ישראל אפילו כמלא נימא עוד יש לתרץ כי יונה דעתו היה
>   ללכת אל נינוה בשליחות האל אלא רצה להאריך הזמן אולי תתמלא סאתם בין כך
>   ובין כך ולפיכך ברח לתרשיש להאריך הזמן ומשם ילך לנינוה ומדברי המתרגם
>   נראה שכל זה קודם שאמר לו הקב"ה שילך לנינוה שתרגם ויקם יונה לברוח
>   תרשישה מלפני ה' וקם יונה למיערק לימא מן קדם דאיתנבי בשמא דה' ונחת ליפו
>   וגומר וצריך לומר שידע במראה הנבואה שהיה הקב"ה רוצה לשלוח אותו וברח
>   לחוצה לארץ כדי שלא תשרה עליו הנבואה ושיעור הכתוב כך ויקם יונה לברוח
>   תרשישה מלפני שהיה אליו הדבור הנזכר למעלה וזהו מלפני השם ואע"ג דלשון
>   הכתוב דחוק קצת הענין מתיישב שפיר לפי דרך זה