# Does one have to listen to an angel?

Tags: theology, sin, malach-angel, nevua-prophecy

Does one now (or ever in the past) have to listen to the instructions of an angel?

If so, would that include listening if the angel told you to violate a Torah commandment (either temporarily or permanently)?

Comment: [דברי הרב ודברי התלמיד דברי מי שומעין?](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=42b&format=pdf)

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess the question is then is the angel a talmid or essentially an extension of the rav?

Comment: When the Toras Yekusiel was asked to sign a cherem (excommunication) against the chassidim he refused. He was asked: even the Vilna Gaon who is "malach hashem tzvakos" signed, to which he replied - an angel told Avraham not to slaughter his son. But to tell him to take his son up, that came directly from Hashem because even if a malach would tell me to shecht someone I would not listen. (From Sippurey Chassidim)

Comment: @Michoel By that logic, wouldn't you need a Beis Din of 23 to effect a Cherem?

Comment: IIRC, the latter post-exilic prophets all had their prophecies through angelic revelations.

Comment: Do angels "speak"?

Comment: I think what various people are saying is, Of course you don't have to listen to an angel. You have to listen to G-d. There are various guidelines for deciding when a vision is properly prophetic, and in that case you would be allowed and required to follow the vision even to temporarily violate the Torah - again within various guidelines.

Comment: See Joshua end of Chapter 5.

Comment: Aren't malachim none other than G-d's tools of communicating with prophets? A malach has no free will, so if a malach is telling you something it is 100% from none other than G-d.

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam writes, both in *Hil. Yesodei HaTorah* (7:6) and in [*Moreh Nevuchim* (2:34)](http://books.google.com/books?id=a2dRAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA223&ots=6HwlYSORi8&dq=identical%20with%20the%20parallel%20passage%20in%20Deuteronomy%20which%20God%20is%20represented%20to%20have%20addressed%20to%20Moses%20at%20the%20revelation%20on%20Mount%20Sinai,&pg=PA223#v=onepage&q&f=false) that, with the exception of Moses, all prophets received their prophecy through angels. As we are obligated to obey a prophet, it would seem that the fact that the prophecy was conveyed through an angel is not a problem. This would include a temporary command to violate a Biblical commandment (with the exception of idolatry). (*Hil. Yesodei HaTorah* 9:3-5)

However, not every apparent revelation qualifies as full fledged prophecy. The Rambam discusses the rules for determining when a person is a full-fledged prophet in *Hil. Yesodei HaTorah* ([chapters 7](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904991/jewish/Chapter-Seven.htm)-10). If the prophecy is not a full-fledged prophecy, then one certainly would not be *obligated* - in the full sense - to obey, especially if the supposed command was in violation of *halacha* (in which case one would be forbidden from obeying the command).

Whether such a revelation could be used to help resolve a halachic question, or whether - in the absence of any halachic issues - one would be best advised to follow such instructions, is a far more complex question. In this regard I would recommend reading R' Reuven Margolios' introduction to his edition of שו"ת מן השמים (printed by Mossad HaRav Kook), where he discusses the various lower forms of *ruach hakodesh* that have existed in the generation since the end of prophecy, and how much authority they are given in halachic matters.

Comment: What is the rambam's m'kor?

Comment: See the Rambam in Moreh Nevuchim (2:34 - I inadvertently wrote 2:24 in my answer) where he explains how he derives this concept from the Torah. (Also related are *Hil. Yesodei HaTorah* 2:7 - in his discussion of the different kinds of angels - and 7:1 - in his discussion of how prophecy functions.)

Comment: Tangent: would the sources in your second paragraph help with answering http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11546/how-and-when-does-a-prophet-know-that-its-god-whos-speaking-to-him ?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Perhaps. Interestingly, the Rambam doesn't really directly address how a prophet knows for himself if he is a legitimate prophet. Rather, he discusses how the community is able to determine if someone who claims to be a prophet is legitimate. However, there would clearly be some overlap between the two areas (in that if someone is receiving "prophetic" visions when he is clearly unworthy of doing so, or if his visions are of an inherently invalid nature, then he should recognize that he is not actually experiencing true prophecy).

Comment: "all prophets received their prophecy through angels" is incorrect. The Rambam actually writes that with the exception of Moses, all prophetic received their prophecy through dreams or visions [of] angels.