If someone hears G-d's voice but decides not to follow it, can G-d influence their behavior to cause unwanted problems, ultimately coercing them...?
If someone feels what they classify as the voice of G-d urging them to take a specific action but chooses not to follow it, could G-d influence their behavior in ways that lead to unwanted problems, ultimately coercing them to follow His will?
Note: alternatively the question can be formulated as: does god use coercive means to make us do his will?

That would seem so, as the Abarbanel interprets Yonah 1:4 as: "And since Jonah was going against His Will, G-d made a great wind on the sea and there was a mighty storm and about this the psukim explain the reason for the storms. "

This question is interesting, but needs more focus. "Circumstances", "behaviours", "unwanted problems", "compelling", "comply" (and "compelling to comply") are all general, broad, undefined, and/or ambiguous, so please try to focus the question by defining and limiting these.

It's not just about adjusting the words, but explaining them. Maybe try giving your own example (also explain exactly what you want us to take from your quote)

Maybe the op is trying to prove the point by saying that Yonah fled away from G-D’s service but G-d said "stop. I will give a storm so that your plan will not go as you want. I am in control"?

The question presents the example that it can happen.  The original question is a type of yes or no. It's a self-answered question.

"feels what they classify as"? Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11546/ (Also note that there are certain signs that immediately identify a prophecy as false, including if it involves a call to idol worship or otherwise contradicts the Torah, if it permanently abrogates a law in the Torah, or if it involves a statement ostensibly made in HaShem's Name to the prophet that predicts something positive for the Jewish People and that is then subsequently falsified).

I am willing to reopen the question based on your clarification now, but I would still recommend giving an example
