# Why does Yona flee?

Tags: yonah-jonah-book-of

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did Yonah run away?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11510/why-did-yonah-run-away)

Sefer Yona 1:3 What is this silly game of running away? Obivously a person who has achieved nevius can't believe fleeing is a real solution. What was he hoping to accomplish by this?